# How to open TypeScript and JavaScript files in VSCode from clicking a link in iTerm2?

Tags: terminal

When I click a JavaScript link in iTerm2, it opens up SublimeText (even though I have configured the `EDITOR` env var to `code` for VSCode instead, see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/729790/how-to-debug-why-iterm2-is-loading-sublimetext-instead-of-vscode-as-the-default) for more info on that problem).

Now, when I click a TypeScript file in iTerm2, I'm noticing it's trying to open some random app I have never heard of, for the `.ts` file.

[image]

How can I configure it so specific files by extension open using VSCode when a link is clicked for them? It could be more than just JS/TS files, like PDFs, or custom programming language files, etc..

Also curious how the defaults are configured for this, because it always opens weird apps for different file extensions so maybe there is an app-level binding in Swift/MacOS apps to the terminal or something, would be curious to find out how that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In newer versions of iTerm2, you can enable VS Code as the default editor to open filenames by opening `iTerm2 > Preferences > Profiles > Advanced > Semantic History` and then selecting "Open with editor..." and "VS Code" from the two drop downs.

[image: Open iTerm2 preferences > profiles > advanced > Semantic History]

PS: `.ts` files are historically video files, so that's why it's trying to open it with a media application.